# Jupyter notebook - drop down code

Tags: ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I am doing a Udemy course using Jupyter Notebook. On the tutorial the tutor gets drop down "help" after writing code. On my version this doesn't happen. Any idea how I can activate this feature?

[image]

Comment: have you tried with different browsers ? How did you install Jupyter ? What is the OS ?

Comment: OS is WIN7 -- I instaled through Anaconda. Tried with both IE and Chrome and still doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

Press the `Shift` and the `Tab` key at the same time when the cursor is inside the parenthesis.

Comment: Hi -- I've tried pressing shift+tab, but it didn't work. I am using Jupyter ... have tried in both Chrome and Explorer, any other ideas?